# Как написать программу, которая авторизируется в мессенджере и выполняет какие-то действия?

Tags: python

Я начинающий программист на python, пока особо не разбираюсь в кодинге и знаю язык на уровне базы, переменные, циклы, массивы… Не так давно столкнулся с необходимостью написать программу, которая бы авторизировалась в мессенджере по готовым данным для авторизации и циклично выполняла бы описанные действия, например рассылала бы рекламу раз в 10 минут. В интернете ничего интересующего не нашёл, есть ли какие-то материалы, которые могут помочь реализовать такую программу или совет, который облегчил бы мои изыскания?

Comment: Зависит от мессенджера. Почти у каждого есть api, с помощью которого можно это устроить. Поищите python api библиотеку для нужного вам мессенджера и работайте по документации или гайдам

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Скажите что за мессенджер. Может помогу